# Changing a custom accessoryView in a uitableviewcell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to change the custom accessoryView of a uitableviewcell immediately after the user clicks on the cell. How would I do this?

For the record, I'm using Matt Gallagher' custom table view tutorial:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Download link for source: http://projectswithlove.com/projects/EasyCustomTable.zip

---

EDIT

Tried this code, but it just changes the accessory AFTER touch-up. Also tried willSelectRowAtIndexPath with same result.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicatorSelected.png"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:indicatorImage] autorelease];
    return indexPath;
 }
```

---

EDIT

Problem solved by making the background image of the cell contain the accessories. so the accessory was 'faked' by making it part of the image

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can try to reload the cell in willSelectRowAtIndexPath/didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIImage *indicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"indicatorSelected.png"];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:indicatorImage] autorelease];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,nil] withRowAnimation:NO];
 }
```

Another recommendation: 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath **returns void** not NSIndexPath.

Comment: willSelectRowAtIndexPath returns NSIndexPath*, not void.

Comment: You right. It was my misstake with `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` (edited). But `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` returns void. **Did you just -1** becaus of this wrong recommendation for (`willSelectRowAtIndexPath`) or **is there also a misstake** in the implementation example?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the accessoryView in the selection method as shown:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = newView;
}
```

This just grabs the current cell that was selected and then changes the accessory view of it.  Your view object would go where newView is.

Answer (score 0):

Use the highlightedImage property of UIImageView:

```
UIImageView* arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:normalImage];
arrowView.highlightedImage = selectedImage;
cell.accessoryView = arrowView;
[arrowView release];
```